# Adding function parameters to Keras backend function for Grad-CAM to work with dropout

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Im trying to implement [Grad-CAM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02391) as explained in [this](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python) amazing book. However in the model from the book they are not using a dropout layer but I am so the example code provided does not run. 
I am using the following model:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 15, 15, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 13, 13, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 6, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 4, 128)         73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 2, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 43)                5547
```

And would like to get the following code working:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import mean, function, gradients
roadwork_output = model.output[:, 25] # 25 is the label for roadwork
last_conv_layer = model.get_layer('conv2d_3')
grads = gradients(roadwork_output, last_conv_layer.output)[0]
pooled_grads = mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))
iterate = function([model.input],
                     [pooled_grads, last_conv_layer.output[0]])
pooled_grads_value, conv_layer_output_value = iterate([resized_images[4].reshape(1,32,32,3)])
for i in range(128): # 128 channels in last conv layer
    conv_layer_output_value[:, :, i] *= pooled_grads_value[i]
heatmap = np.mean(conv_layer_output_value, axis=-1)
```

However im getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1349     try:
-> 1350       return fn(*args)
   1351     except errors.OpError as e:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1328                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1329                                    status, run_metadata)
   1330 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    472             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 473             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    474     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dropout/keras_learning_phase' with dtype bool
     [[Node: dropout/keras_learning_phase = Placeholder[dtype=DT_BOOL, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Mean_8/_187 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_200_Mean_8", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-b1b0b22c0d54> in <module>()
      7 iterate = function([model.input],
      8                      [pooled_grads, last_conv_layer.output[0]])
----> 9 pooled_grads_value, conv_layer_output_value = iterate([resized_images[4].reshape(1,32,32,3)])
     10 for i in range(128): # 128 channels in last conv layer
     11     conv_layer_output_value[:, :, i] *= pooled_grads_value[i]

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2551     session = get_session()
   2552     updated = session.run(
-> 2553         fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict, **self.session_kwargs)
   2554     return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2555 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    893     try:
    894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
    896       if run_metadata:
    897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1126     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1127       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1128                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1129     else:
   1130       results = []

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1342     if handle is None:
   1343       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1344                            options, run_metadata)
   1345     else:
   1346       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1361         except KeyError:
   1362           pass
-> 1363       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1364 
   1365   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dropout/keras_learning_phase' with dtype bool
     [[Node: dropout/keras_learning_phase = Placeholder[dtype=DT_BOOL, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Mean_8/_187 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_200_Mean_8", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'dropout/keras_learning_phase', defined at:
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 478, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-8-50ed28ee661a>", line 12, in <module>
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/models.py", line 514, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/topology.py", line 258, in __call__
    output = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 652, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/layers/core.py", line 117, in call
    training = K.learning_phase()
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/backend.py", line 331, in learning_phase
    phase = array_ops.placeholder(dtype='bool', name='keras_learning_phase')
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1680, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3141, in _placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3160, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/henke/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1625, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dropout/keras_learning_phase' with dtype bool
     [[Node: dropout/keras_learning_phase = Placeholder[dtype=DT_BOOL, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Mean_8/_187 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_200_Mean_8", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Why am I getting this error and what do I need to change to fix it?

Comment: There are two reasons for this. First, you need to specify to the gradient calculation function that whether you are in training phase or test phase. Second, when you add dropout, some of the activations are dropped(becomes zero), so even if you get it running, it would not make much sense, if the dropout is active, you don't know whether the activation worked or lost due to dropout

Comment: Could you provide code in an example on how to do this and I will accept it as answer it if works or are you saying that I cant use Grad-CAM if im using dropout?

Comment: Add this line of code `keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)` after this line `from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import mean, function, gradients`

Comment: Even after adding that line im still getting the same error. What else can cause this issue?

Comment: I need to look at the code and run it once locally then, can't suggest anything other than the one I already suggested. But did you read the second point in my first comment?

Comment: Yes but I dont get the last point, the dropout will not be active when i make predictions only in training so the dropout will not affect how Grad-CAM works?

Comment: Also I will try to use set_learning_phase before to define the model, i missed this last night when i tried it the first time.

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: Yup it did not work, i gave up and removed the dropout. Found lots of githud issues regarding the set_learning_phase functions not working as expected.

Comment: May be. But the thing is, if you use dropout and then try to look where your network is focusing via CAM, it might not work out. The reason is when you apply dropout, you don't know which neurons in that layer are going to be off. That will break the cluster of activation you want in CAM. In some cases, it might work out, in other it might not. You never know!!